# Backend order grid modification inducing filtering error

Tags: magento-1, filter, sql, order-grid

I added columns in the backend order grid using

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
            'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing"',
            array('company')
        );
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('payment'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method'=>'method'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

...

        $this->addColumn('company', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Company'),
            'index' => 'company',
        ));


...

        $this->addColumn('payment_method', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
            'index' => 'payment_method',
        ));

...

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Displaying the order grid works well, BUT, when I try filtering according to the payment method, it generates a magento error...

```
a:5:{i:0;s:348:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payment_method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing" WHERE (payment_method LIKE '%systempay\\_standard%')";i:1;s:6920:"#0 /homepages/20/d524244365/htdocs/e-circuits/magentoNV/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Update :

Error 1

```
a:5:{i:0;s:340:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payment_method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing" WHERE (payment_method LIKE '%banktransfer%')";i:1;s:6920:"#0 magento/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 magento/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 magento/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 magento/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(516): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(563): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 magento/app/code/community/Raveinfosys/Deleteorder/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php(49): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Raveinfosys_Deleteorder_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#21 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/homepages/20/d...')
#32 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#40 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 magento/index.php(96): Mage::run('fr_store', 'store')
#45 {main}";s:3:"url";s:72:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/626814ee7a201ca1950642dcef88e698/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved with below answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I think getSelect() won't work more then 1 time. So please use this method and try with rest of your default code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->getSelect()->join(
        array('address' => $collection->getTable("sales/order_address")),
        'main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing"',
        array('company')
    );
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('payment'=>$collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method'=>'method'));

$this->setCollection($collection);
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it does not work... I also added the company column, and filtering by company name works well. Only payment method induces an error..

Comment: Can you please try with my updated answer. Just change the table name to address in filter_index.

Comment: still not working, here is the beginning of the log :a:5:{i:0;s:387:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'address.payment_method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing" WHERE (company LIKE '%NOMISMA%') AND (address.payment_method LIKE '%banktransfer%')";i:1;s:6920:"#0 /homepages/20/d524244365/htdocs/e-circuits/magentoNV/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_ex

Comment: Please try with my improved answer and just change this method only and rest will your default code.

Comment: idem : a:5:{i:0;s:340:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payment_method' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "billing" WHERE (payment_method LIKE '%banktransfer%')";i:1;s:3853:"#0 /homepages/20/d524244365/htdocs/e-circuits/magentoNV/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: Can you please try again with my improved answer.

Comment: not working... Same thing. When I try filtering the grid using the payment method, I am sent back to backend HomePage. When trying I click to orders I have a magento error. I need to disconnect and reconnect to backend to make it rework... Got 2 exception files : please see my question update

Comment: return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection(); <--- this was the missing bit of magic for me, thanks :)